# Visual Studio Folder file path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, ado.net

I have folder in my project called "Database". Inside that folder is the file "topicalconcordance.sqlite".  I am trying to locate the db and connect to it like so:

```
using (DbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=myDbPath/topicalconcordance.sqlite"))
```

How do I modify my path here so it points to the internal .sqlite file in my folder?

Is there a better way to access and modify and store an internal file like I have?

Answer (score 1):

You can store you connection in your app.config file, or you can store it in a setting file. Then you can just change the path of the connection, without having to rebuild you application.

You app.config file will look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Conn" connectionString="Data Source=myDbPath/topicalconcordance.sqlite" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

You can call get the connection in code behind.

```
string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString();
```

Comment: thanks! And what is the path to internal project files? Could I just do Database/topicalconcordance.sqlite ? Or is there some special way to write the path of project folders?  I mean I wouldn't have to do "C:\Users..." would I.  For instance, on the iPhone, I add my database to a project folder, and then instead of using some certain path, I just access the "mainFileBundle"

Comment: Yeah you should be able use the path as you specified, I know know if you need to specify the full path if you database is within your root folder.

Comment: I still need some help with this issue. To recap, I have added a folder in my project within Visual Studio 2010 ("Add-> New Folder").  I named that folder to Database.  The full path to this folder is: "C:\Spentak\visual studio 2010\Projects\TopicalConcordance\"  In this folder I added my Database file (topicalconcordance.sqlite).  The only way I can access this is by typing in the full path.  I need a generic path though. This won't work if I give my solution to someone else. They would have to modify the path.  How do I reference an internal file, without ever having to change the path?

Comment: Have you tried this. "Data Source=/myDbPath/topicalconcordance.sqlite" that or this "Data Source=\\myDbPath\\topicalconcordance.sqlite"

Comment: @spentak let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1127/discussion-between-jethro-and-spentak)

Comment: That is what i'm trying to get working here.  I can get it to work fine putting in the full path on the local harddrive.  But lets say I give my visual studio solution to someone else.  They are going to need to modify that path to get it to work.  What I need is a universal internal filepath.